# Multiple Aliases for the same Instagram account? Is it possible to make the same Instagram Account findable under different names?

Tags: account-management, instagram, alias

Is it possible to make the same Instagram Account findable under different names, so that when googling for “John Doe Illustration” or “John Doe Illustrations” (note the plural S) the very same Instagram account gets listed? In other words: Is it possible to create Instagram aliases so to say?

Or is there any external workaround to achieve the same effect? Two accounts, where the second is a mirror/automated sync of the first account? (A bit cumber-some)...